# Does Magento support USPS Parcel Select Shipping Method

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, usps

The requirement for shipping method for USPS on the site I'm working on is Parcel Select. I don't seem to be able to locate the Parcel Select method in the option list. As part of the requirement, the Parcel Select is also need to be setup as Free Method.

We're on latest Magento CE 1.9.1.0. Is the option available or is it under different name? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just let the customer select "Free Shipping" (you can change this name) during checkout and you can ship it to them in whatever fashion you want.

Comment: @pspahn That is one option definitely I'm looking to do, but we are considering adding more shipping options and since Parcel Select will be one of them, I'm just wondering where it is.

Comment: Apparently there are other requirements for using Parcel Select. See some of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=magento+parcel+select